# Populate multiple sql queries based on Drop down selection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to **PHP** and **SQL** and would like to know what is the best solution to my issue.

I currently have a **PHP** page (*profile.php*) that contains the following three select queries:

```
$academic = "SELECT * FROM t12019 WHERE `Student ID` = {$id}";
$resultb = mysqli_query($conn,$academic); 

$stoplight = "SELECT * FROM t1stoplight19 WHERE `Student ID` = {$id}";
$resultc = mysqli_query($conn,$stoplight); 

$attendance = "SELECT * FROM t1attendance2019 WHERE `Student ID` = {$id}";
$resultd = mysqli_query($conn,$attendance);
```

`$id` comes from a `$_POST` selection from the previous page.

the tables for each query is coded in, however, I would like them to be a variable that can be updated from a dropdown selection on the page.

What I imagine, is a selection box on the *profiles.php* where a user can select one of '**Term 1**','**Term 2**', '**Term 3**', '**Term 4**'. The tables for each query will then be updated accordingly for the selection.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please read carefully about SQL injections before doing such things! As a first start I would suggest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: First, to prevent sql injection refer this article.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: you need to passed selected `value` to your query ,didn't understand your question?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On dropdown selection, by javascript submit form and update the respective code. Please refer below sample code.

**HTML code:**

```
<form action="update.php" id="updateFrm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <select name="term" id="term" onchange="updateTable()">
        <option value="term_1">Term 1</option>
        <option value="term_2">Term 2</option>
        <option value="term_3">Term 3</option>
        <option value="term_4">Term 4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateTable() {
      document.getElementById("updateFrm").submit();

  }

</script>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$term = $_POST['term'];

if($term == 'term_1'){
  $sql = "UPDATE t12019 ". "SET field1 = $term ".
    "WHERE `Student ID` = $id" ;
  $retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

  if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
  }
  echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}else if($term == 'term_2'){
  $sql = "UPDATE t1stoplight19 ". "SET field1 = $term ".
    "WHERE `Student ID` = $id" ;
  $retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

  if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
  }
  echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}.....and so on.


?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much @Sangita. This is exactly what I was looking for.